# Dynamic Height of an Accordion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

We are using an accordion to show an unordered list. The second element of the list contains a table.
The heights of divs are being set dynamically, based on content height, in some Javascript that we are using via CDN.

Code in CSHTML file

```
<li class="accordion__item">
        <button class="accordion__trigger" aria-controls="Categoryarea">
            @SharedLocalizer["Manage Category"]
            <div class="accordion__arrow"></div>
        </button>
        <div class="accordion__contents" id="Categoryarea">
            <a href="#" class="link link--no-underline color-green" data-modal-trigger="CreateNewItemCategoryGrpModal">@SharedLocalizer["Add New Category"]<i class=" fa-fw fas fa-plus"></i></a>
            <div class="table">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead class="card-header">
                         3 Column names
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        7 rows 3 columns each
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

Inspect element in Chrome

```
<li class="accordion__item" data-accordion-item-height="445" style="height: 49px;">
        <button class="accordion__trigger" aria-controls="accordion-control-325" data-accordion-trigger-height="49" aria-expanded="false">
            Manage Category
            <div class="accordion__arrow"></div>
        </button>
        <div class="accordion__contents" id="accordion-control-325" data-accordion-contents-height="396" aria-hidden="true">
                <a href="#" class="link link--no-underline color-green" data-modal-trigger="CreateNewItemCategoryGrpModal" data-modal-trigger-initialised="true">Add New Category<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-plus fa-w-14 fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="plus" role="img" xmlns="some value" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="some value"></path></svg><!-- <i class=" fa-fw fas fa-plus"></i> --></a>
                <div class="table">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                            table with contents         
                    </table>
                </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

When the accordion is collapsed, it takes the height of "accordion__trigger" i.e 49px.
When the accordion is expanded, it takes the sum of the heights of "accordion__trigger" and "accordion__contents" as its height i.e 49+396 = 445px

If there are more than 5-6 rows in the table, the height of the div "accordion__contents" is not correct. When inspecting the element in chrome, I can see that the height should be 460px instead on 396px.

Due to this, when the accordion is expanded, later rows of the table hid behind the next item in the list.

**Approach** - As a work around, if I can add 50-60 px to the height of "accordion__contents", then this might solve the issue.
(I am not sure about this. Open to other approaches.)

How can I override the height of the div "accordion__contents"?

Comment: write your code in snip or codepen

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Probably the issue is coming when you store the heights of you `accordion__contents` in the beginning and they are not accurate.

Comment: @Rado the heights are being calculated in the js file and we are using it via CDN. I have looked into this js file, but it a minified version so I was not able to make much sense out of it. I am not sure how can I create a minimal reproducible example for this. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: You can use [codepen](https://codepen.io/) to create an example of you issue. @Novice101